# XCrossingEvent and x_root, y_root

Tags: x11, xlib

I am chasing a bug that I suspect is my own misunderstanding about X:

TL;DR - Sometimes XEnterNotify events give global mouse coordinates that don't correspond to the window being entered.

I'm modifying a tiling window manager (ratpoison). The screen is divided into frames, each of which may contain a mapped window. If a frame contains no window, I'd like to focus the frame. So I ask for EnterNotify events on the root window, cast the XEvent to an XCrossingEvent, and then look at x_root and y_root to figure out where the mouse is on the screen. I expect to get the global screen coordinates. The problem is that sometimes when I move the mouse over the empty frame, I get an EnterNotify event on the root window, but the (x_root, y_root) members of the event give a point in the frame I came from (i.e., not at an exposed part of the root window).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is the following:

The mouse coordinates are not guaranteed to be in sync with anything in particular. The only thing that seems really to be guaranteed is that the mouse was at one point at these coordinates and that a later event will have a later mouse position. In order to know the true mouse position, I either need to listen to motion events on the root window (so that I will eventually get the information I want) or else call (probably) XQueryPointer().

Note that I am not 100% certain of this answer.